# Calculating Euclidean distance using Magic Methods in Python 3

Tags: python, oop

I have a code that calculates Euclidean distance for me:

```
class Point:
    """A point in two-dimensional space."""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._x == other._x and self._y == other._y

    def distance(self, other):
        new_x = self._x - other._x
        new_y = self._y - other._y
        print(new_x,'  ',new_y)
        return (new_x ** 2 + new_y ** 2) ** 0.5

p1 = Point(10, 4)
p2 = Point(3, 1)


print('Euclidean distance : 'p1.distance(p2))
```

However, now I want to calculate this distance using magic methods in python like `__sub__` and `__pow__`. I've managed to implement `__sub__` but I don't know how to implement for `__pow__` and square root. This is my code so far:

```
class Point_1(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y


    def setX(self, x,y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def getX(self):
        return self._x,self._y


    def __sub__ (self, other ):
        return Point_1(self._x - other._x, self._y - other._y)

    def __pow__(self,p):
        return Point_1(self._x ** p, self._y **p)




p1 = Point_1(10,4)
print(p1.getX())

p2 = Point_1(3,1)
print(p2.getX())

p3 = p1 - p2
```

How can I implement the rest of the formula using magic methods. I'm really confused. Help would me appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your code runs properly before posting it. Currently it throws an error due to `Point_1` not being defined. And the second class doesn't instantiate properly.

Comment: yeah they're instantiating objects with a name that doesn't match the class', starting from there we might go somewhere

Comment: It should be working now.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do here. Why do you think that using a magic method here is appropriate? Magic methods allow you to invoke a method when a standard operator (or function) is used with your object. Which standard operator do you intend to use to invoke the Euclidean distance?

Comment: So I am just learning about how I could use magic methods. I agree using them here is not exactly useful but since I made a code with euclidean distance I thought it would be nice to see how these magic methods work in this case. So my code, for now, returns the difference (p3) but now I want to take that and calculate the square of my x and y using magic method pow but I don't know how to do that and then want to take the result of that and compute a square root using magic method and that would be my Euclidean distance

Comment: You are trying to implement vectors, not point, that might be the source of your confusion.

Comment: `__pow__()` for points makes little sense for me but as a learning exercise it is just fine. While at it, implement `__repr__()` and possible setters and getters (instead of the awkward `getX()` and `getY()`). Alternatively, get rid of the underscore in `_x` and `_y`. What is the purpose of making them "private"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned, it may not be a good idea to use a Point class to represent vectors. It's ok in simple programs, but it can get confusing in more complex code. The usual practice is to make points immutable. But anyway...

To do this Euclidean distance operation we can "abuse" the new [`__matmul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__matmul__) magic method. This method is invoked by the `@` operator. Here's a short demo based on your code. Notice that I'm using `x` and `y` as the attributes, there's no good reason to mark them as private.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def __add__ (self, other ):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__ (self, other ):
        return Point(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __pow__(self, p):
        return Point(self.x ** p, self.y **p)

    def __abs__(self):
        d = self ** 2
        return (d.x + d.y) ** 0.5

    def __matmul__(self, other):
        ''' Euclidean distance between self & other '''
        return abs(self - other)

# Test

a = Point(5, 6)
b = Point(2, 2)
print(a + b)
print(a - b)
print(a @ b)
```

**output**

```
Point(7, 8)
Point(3, 4)
5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense for the difference of two points to be a point. It seems the object you are trying to implement is in fact a vector.

Then the distance corresponds to the norm of a vector, implemented with `__abs__`.

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._coords = args

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(*[x + y for x, y in zip(self._coords, other._coords)])

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(*[x - y for x, y in zip(self._coords, other._coords)])

    def __abs__(self):
        """Euclidian norm of the vector"""
        return sum(x**2 for x in self._coords) ** (1 / 2)
```

### Example

```
v1 = Vector(1, 3)
v2 = Vector(4, -1)

print(abs(v2 - v1)) # 5.0

# Also works in higher dimensions
v3 = Vector(1, -1, 0)
v4 = Vector(4, 6, -2)

print(abs(v3 - v4)) # 7.87
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your definition of `__pow__` is a bit nonstandard for vectors.

But as it is, the distance of two points `p1` and `p2` could be written as `sum((p1 - p2)**2)**.5`. So we need your `__pow__` method, your `__sub__` method, and the only other addition is an `__iter__` method which allows `sum` to work:

```
class Point:
    """A point in two-dimensional space."""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._x == other._x and self._y == other._y

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Point(self._x - other._x, self._y - other._y)

    def __pow__(self, power):
        return Point(self._x**power, self._y**power)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self._x
        yield self._y

    def distance(self, other):
        return sum((self - other)**2)**.5

p1 = Point(2, 3)
p2 = Point(5, -1)

print(p1.distance(p2))
Out: 5.0
```

That's the shortest way based on your existing code anyway. You could experiment further by adding a scalar multiplication method and an addition method and then defining sub as `p1 + (-1)*p2`. You can also make things a bit easier on yourself by implementing a `__repr__` method.

Comment: Thank you. I think I get it now.

Comment: Although, this mathematically makes no sense to call those Points

Comment: Makes sense to me. Anyway, it's a pedagogical example for OOP. As others have made clear, this is not, in terms of programming, mathematics or optimisation, the best way to write the code.

Comment: In your definition of `abs()` why do you use non-Euclidean distance? (`return self._x**2 + self._y**2`)

Comment: @AGNGazer A mistake, thanks. My code was squaring the elements twice. `abs` should really have been a `sum`. I will change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your second class works for me. I do not see any issues with it:

```
In [9]: class Point_1(object):
   ...:     
   ...:     def __init__(self, x, y):
   ...:         self._x = x
   ...:         self._y = y
   ...:   
   ...:     
   ...:     def setX(self, x,y):
   ...:         self._x = x
   ...:         self._y = y
   ...:  
   ...:     def getX(self):
   ...:         return self._x,self._y
   ...:     
   ...:     
   ...:     def __sub__ (self, other ):
   ...:         return Point_1(self._x - other._x, self._y - other._y)
   ...:     
   ...:     def __pow__(self,p):
   ...:         return Point_1(self._x ** p, self._y **p)
```

And then:

```
In [14]: p1 = Point_1(10,4)
    ...: print(p1.getX())
    ...: 
    ...: p2 = Point_1(3,1)
    ...: print(p2.getX())
    ...: 
    ...: p3 = p1 - p2
    ...: 
    ...: 
(10, 4)
(3, 1)

In [15]: p3.getX()
Out[15]: (7, 3)
```

Call it vector or point or whatever, it seems to be doing what you want it to do.