# A point class and a rectangle class without using inheritance

Tags: python

I am trying to create a point class that has the data attribute of floating point values 'x' and 'y' to therefore define a location of a point in 2D space. Additionally I want to have methods of **init** such as it being an initialization of default values x = 0 and y = 0. And then a move function which accepts the 'x' and 'y' as a new location of the point. And finally a function which tells the distance to a point. I want this to return the Euclidian distance from this point to another point at x, y.  How would this be done?

Here is the code I have so far for the above description:

```
import math

class Point:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0 # initialize to 0
        self.y = 0 # initialize to 0

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Could use help on this and the Eucliean distance from this point to another point at x,y. Not sure if I have the right idea so far. New to python so don't know how to test the functionality of this code. Would appreciate the help!

After that part I'd to be able to define two points at two opposite corners of a rectangle and use the Points defined above without using inheritance. Any ideas on how to create this class?

Comment: `def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):` would be better, so you can set the coords when you create a Point. You might find this answer interesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/52388373/4014959

Comment: You seem to have a pretty clear picture of what the class supposed to look like. What exactly prevents you from simply writing it?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks! I know this is super basic but the Euclidean distance would simply be having two points (x1,y1) (x2,y2) and plugging them into the formula: sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 )…. so in python that would be math.Sqrt( (x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 ) ?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the part which is confusing me is taking two points and defining two opposite corners of a rectangle using the Points defined above aka not using inheritance. Not sure how that would be done.

Comment: Correct. Although it's `math.sqrt`. As the linked answers show, a nice way to do that is to give the Point class an `__abs__` magic method that calculates the distance of a point to the origin. And if you also give Point a `__sub__` method then you can do `abs(a-b)` to get the distance between points a & b.

Comment: BTW, you should ask about your Rectangle class in a fresh question. You can link the new question to this one if you want. Hint: In Rectangle you can do this `def __init__(self, point1, point2):`

Comment: @PM2Ring why wouldn't it be 4 points in the parameter? one for each corner

Comment: Because you said that you want to define two points at two opposite corners of a rectangle. If you allow the caller to pass 4 points then you have to check that the 4 points actually define a rectangle. It's simpler if they can only pass opposite corner points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (comments in the code):

#### example:

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x: float=0.0, y: float=0.0)-> None:   # assign default values
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move_by(self, dx: float, dy: float)-> None:   # move Point by dx, dy
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy 

    def move_to(self, new_x: float, new_y: float)-> None:   # relocate Point to new x, y position
        self.x = new_x
        self.y = new_y 

    def distance(self, other: 'Point')-> float:   # calculates and returns the Euclidian distance between self and other
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            x0, y0 = self.x, self.y
            x1, y1 = other.x, other.y
            return ((x1 - x0)**2 + (y1 - y0)**2) ** 0.5
        return NotImplemented

    def __str__(self)-> str:    # add a nice string representation
        return f'Point({self.x}, {self.y})'
```

#### tests:

```
p = Point(1, 2)
q = Point()
print(p, q, p.distance(q) == 5**0.5)
p.move_by(.1, -.1)
print(p)
```

#### output:

```
Point(1, 2) Point(0.0, 0.0) True
Point(1.1, 1.9)
```

And the Rectangle class could be like this:  **[edited to add default `Point` values]**

In `Rectangle.__init__`, the min and max values of the x and y values of the `Points` provided as parameters are sorted in order to determine the top left and bottom right points defining the rectangle

```
class Rectangle:
        def __init__(self, p0: Point=Point(), p1: Point=Point(1.0, 1.0))-> None:  # <--- [edit]: now with default values
        x0, y0 = p0.x, p0.y
        x1, y1 = p1.x, p1.y
        self.topleft = Point(min(x0, x1), max(y0, y1))      # calculate the topleft and bottomright
        self.bottomright = Point(max(x0, x1), min(y0, y1))  # of the bounding box

    def __str__(self)-> str:
        return f'Rectangle defined by bbox at: {self.topleft}, {self.bottomright})'
```

#### tests:

```
p = Point(1, 2)
q = Point()
print(p, q, p.distance(q) == 5**0.5)
p.move_by(.1, -.1)
print(p)

r = Rectangle(p, q)
print(r)
```

#### output:

```
Point(1, 2) Point(0.0, 0.0) True
Point(1.1, 1.9)
Rectangle defined by bbox at: Point(0.0, 1.9), Point(1.1, 0.0))
```

#### [Edit:] with default values for Points in Rectangle:

```
s = Rectangle()
print(s)
```

#### output:

```
Rectangle defined by bbox at: Point(0.0, 1.0), Point(1.0, 0.0))
```

Comment: Thank you. New to Python, first time seeing : within the parameter list, what does it mean? also the -> None I've never seen these used

Comment: I chose yours as the best answer

Comment: How would I initialize with default p1 = (0,0), p2 = (1,1) within the Rectangle classes' __init__ method? Also I don't understand what is happening with the min and max, please help.

Comment: thank you. I edited the answer to address your questions. In `Rectangle.__init__`, the min and max values of the x and y values of the `Points` are sorted in order to determine the top left and bottom right points defining the rectangle