# Finding Euclidean Distance in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to the python. I just want to find the nearest integer distance between the coordinates using the formula, `​ nint(sqrt((x(1)-x(2))^2 + (y(1)-y(2))^2))` for all the values of x and y.

```
Ids   x       y
1  823170 415922
2  793699 274913
3  981665 218777
4  878910 431320
5  910125 405907
6  906606 245337
7  899056 332853
8  1089292 394322
9  927737 272081
```

how can I implement this in python? I know I must use a for loop,but dont know how to implement this. 
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Forget about Python for some moment, how would you "conceptually" solve this problem?

Comment: What is the data here? A pandas dataframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Euclidean distance using Magic Methods in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387730/calculating-euclidean-distance-using-magic-methods-in-python-3)

Comment: @Willem yes it is a pandas dataframe.